# Magento 1.9.2 Paypal settings don't stick

Tags: paypal, upgrade, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

We are having problem with adding Paypal worldwide standard to our Magento store. When we enter our credentials and press safe configuration the settings are in the greenbar Saved. But they are removed and nothing is saved in Magento. There are no errors on screen or in the logs when this happens. The site has been upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9 a few months ago we didn’t use Paypal at that moment. We have tried changing our currency and tax settings already has anyone seen or heard from these issues and potentially has a fix or workaround for the base magento paypal setup?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your database upgradation is not properly done.

Check your PayPal details in core_config_data table.